# Getting C26485 when using strsafe.h Windows functions

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, visual-c++, strsafe

In this simple example, I get the C26485 error when doing an analysis on the C++ code: `warning C26485: Expression 'sResult2': No array to pointer decay (bounds.3).`

Why is it showing on a `StringCchPrintf()` function when I'm passing it the size of the `WCHAR` array?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <strsafe.h>   
WCHAR sResult2[256]{};
void GetText()
{
    StringCchPrintfW(sResult2, 256, L"this is a %s", L"test");
}

int main()
{
    GetText();
}
```

Comment: That's a code quality warning, specifically to enforce the C++ Core Guidelines, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26485?view=msvc-170. Specifically it wants you to rewrite the function you are calling to take the array by-reference or a `std::span`-like type combining pointer and length as a single argument. Since `StringCchPrintfW` isn't your function, you cannot do anything about this. Best to ignore or suppress the warning. Also consider using `std::format`/`fmt::format` instead of type-unsafe functions like this.